# How to match one of two strings as a condition in bash

Tags: bash, shell

firstly I had very simple script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
if cat /etc/redhat-release | grep -q 'AlmaLinux'; then
    echo "your system is supported"
    MY SCRIPT HERE
else
    echo "Unsupported OS"
    exit0;
fi
```

and it works but I want to add another correct value that will also return "your system is supported" and let me pass the script to go further

so for example if file /etc/redhat-release will contain AlmaLinux or Rockylinux 8 it will work for both AlmaLinux and Rockylinux but if it will contain Centos 6 it will not go further

I tried something along this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if cat '/etc/redhat-release' | grep -q 'AlmaLinux'|| | grep -q 'RockyLinux 8'; then
    echo "your system is supported"
else
    echo "Unsupported OS"
fi
```

but it gives me an error and I am even not sure if this is a right syntax.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Careful, [`sh` is not necessarily `bash`](/q/5725296/4518341)

Comment: BTW, `cat` is unnecessary there. You can just use `grep -q 'AlmaLinux' /etc/redhat-release`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by using a [regex pattern](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)?

```
#!/bin/sh
if cat '/etc/redhat-release' | grep -q -E 'AlmaLinux|RockyLinux 8'; then
    echo "your system is supported"
else
    echo "Unsupported OS"
fi
```

Comment: Eventually get ride of the useless `cat` with: `if grep -q -E 'AlmaLinux|RockyLinux 8' /etc/redhat-release; then`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -qE 'AlmaLinux|RockyLinux 8' /etc/redhat-release
if [ $? ]; then
  echo "your system is supported"
else
  echo "Unsupported OS"
fi
```

Comment: This will fail if the result from `grep` has more than one word (e.g. "RockyLinux 8"). You could fix this by double-quoting the the command substitution, but it's really better to just use the exit status of `grep -q` directly.

Comment: Good catch. Updated.

Comment: Now it'll fail if `grep` prints more than one line. (I don't know the format of `/etc/redhat-release`, but if it's like `/etc/lsb-release` or `/etc/os-release` on Ubuntu, it might have more than one line with the name of the distro.) You want `-ge 1`, but again, it's easier to just use `grep -q`.

Comment: Why doing a `wc`? The exit code of `grep` already tells you whether or not you have a match.

Answer (score 0):

Other perfectly valid detection:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

NAME=unknown
VERSION='??'
if . /etc/os-release && case $NAME in
  *Rocky*)
    case $VERSION in
      8*) ;;
      *) false ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *AlmaLinux*) ;;
  *) false ;;
esac
then
  printf 'Your system %s version %s is supported\n' "$NAME" "$VERSION"
else
  printf '%s %s is not supported!\n' "$NAME" "$VERSION" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```